# Fullscreen background-image with jQuery and Animation

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad

I am using `background-size: cover` on an iPad to display a fullscreen background-image. On `.click(function(){ $(this).addClass('example') });` the div changes its size. So first we got:

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

and afterwards we got something like

```
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
```

Then, on another click the sizes changes back to

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

But the background does not scale anymore. How can I fix this?

[**You can see a video with the error from an ipad right here.**](https://youtu.be/j2EqM_nQ2g4)

Works fine on desktops. [Live version](http://goo.gl/9d4WzB) (div containing the background-image is named `.start-img`

**For everyone who wants to dig deeper:**
On `click` a class `.second` is added to the `div.start-img` which transforms the image. So at first its

```
.start-img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
}
```

The class added or removed by clicking has the following attributes:

```
.start-img.second {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

I guess the problem is, that the background-image stays with the `height: 40%` instead of transforming back to `height: 100%`. It would be great to "force" the background-image to scale again to cover (even if the attribute `background-size: cover` has never changed during the process).

Comment: Can you please share the full code of the `click` event and the css properties?

Comment: Hey @OfirBaruch, I have added the additional information you have requested. The code is quite complex, but (to me) it seems like the code above is all that counts. Just in case I have added a live preview of the site as url. Hope that helps by understanding the problem.

Comment: Since I don't have an iPad the live version isn't effective ;)
When clicking on the "x", the `second` class is being removed?

I would suggest using `document.alert` of the css properties after the event complete so you'll be able to know if it does transforming back to 100% or not.

Comment: Yes the class is being removed. To be honest I have no idea what do you mean by `document.alert`. Do you mean inserting `.removeClass('second').alert('Hello World');` to check if the function fires? Sorry, I am not too long into jquery/javascript.

Comment: Something like: `.removeClass('second').alert($(this).css('width'));` so we can be sure that the width is being updated.

Comment: I have tried to implement your suggestion. I have nested the `.removeClass` in a function `close_second_layer` and a lot of different variations do not work, I do not receive an alert. 
I do not know if thats prohibited on stack overflow, but do you have a contact mail where I could contact you and you charge me for fixing this bug if you are able to? Afterwards you could publish the solution right here! (I am in kind of a hurry because its a project for a client and I do not know skilled developers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79158/discussion-between-marian-rick-and-ofir-baruch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite a special problem. I still do not know why, but there were two commands using [**jquery.transit**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) used to animate the opacity of an element. Deactivating these two lines worked fine for me.

Maybe an iPad got a limited amount of animations it can take via css transitions?

Although I had a script where I created a function like this:

```
example = function(){
   /* other animations to do and the following */
   $('.start-img').addClass('second');
}

$('#example').click(example);
```

which does not work on an iPad, while the following version works perfect:

```
example = function(){
   /* other animations to do and the following */

}

$('#example').click(function(){
   /* other animations to do and the following */
   $('.start-img').addClass('second');
});
```

I cannot explain why and will open another discussion for that in a minimized example.